# React Native: Promise.reject message not displaying upon user clicking button

Tags: javascript, react-native, promise

So this is my applications flow:

Once a user logs in they can click on a hamburger stack which opens up a `CustomDrawer` stack, then click on the `label: "EVENTS"`. This redirects the user to the `AvailableEvents` component:

```
export class AvailableEvents extends PureComponent {
  static propTypes = {
    availableEvents: PropTypes.array,
    displayFooter: PropTypes.bool,
    fetchEvents: PropTypes.func,
    loading: PropTypes.bool,
    navigation: PropTypes.object,
    setSelectedEvent: PropTypes.func,
    userState: PropTypes.string
  };

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      refreshing: false,
      appState: AppState.currentState
    };
  }

  async componentDidMount() {
    AppState.addEventListener("change", this._handleAppStateChange);
    const doRefresh = await shouldRefresh("events");
    if (this.props.availableEvents.length === 0 || doRefresh) {
      this.props.fetchEvents();
    }
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    AppState.removeEventListener("change", this._handleAppStateChange);
  }

  _handleAppStateChange = async appState => {
    if (
      this.state.appState.match(/inactive|background/) &&
      appState === "active"
    ) {
      const doRefresh = await shouldRefresh("events");
      if (doRefresh) {
        this.props.fetchEvents();
      }
    }
    this.setState({ appState });
  };

  _goto = event => {
    this.props.setSelectedEvent(event);
    console.log(this.props.setSelectedEvent(event));
    const title = `${event.LegislatureType} Event`;
    this.props.navigation.navigate("EventDetails", { title });
  };

  _keyExtractor = item => item.Key;

  _renderEvent = ({ item }) => {
    return (
      <EventFeedCard
        style={listStyles.push}
        mainActionButtonPress={() => this._goto(item)}
        event={item}
      />
    );
  };

  _onRefresh = async () => {
    try {
      this.setState({ refreshing: true });
      this.props
        .fetchEvents()
        .then(() => {
          this.setState({ refreshing: false });
        })
        .catch(() => {
          this.setState({ refreshing: false });
        });
    } catch (e) {
      this.setState({ refreshing: false });
    }
  };
  // when clicking EVENTS from CustomDrawer it loads from here
  render() {
    if (this.props.loading && !this.state.refreshing) {
      console.log(
        "Loading from AvailableEvents: ",
        this.props.loading && !this.state.refreshing
      );
      return <Loading />;
    }
```

which is the parent component to `EventFeedCard`:

```
const EventFeedCard = props => {
  //prettier-ignore
  const source = props.event.ImageURL ? {uri: props.event.ImageURL} : defaultImage;
  //prettier-ignore
  const contentStyles = deviceHelpers.isTablet ? feedContentStyles.tabletContent : feedContentStyles.content;
  //prettier-ignore
  const contentFlexer = deviceHelpers.isTablet ? {flex: 2} : {flex: 1};
  //prettier-ignore
  const eventLocation = `${props.event.Location.City}, ${props.event.Location.StateAbbreviation}`;
  const displayTotal = props.isRegistered && !props.event.IsFree;

  return (
    <Card style={props.style}>
      <View style={feedContentStyles.header}>
        <Text style={feedContentStyles.title}>
          {`NFIB ${props.event.LegislatureType.toUpperCase()} EVENT`}
        </Text>
        <Text style={feedContentStyles.postDate}>
          {`On ${format(props.event.StartDate, "MMM D, YYYY")}`}
        </Text>
      </View>
      {!deviceHelpers.isTablet && (
        <View style={feedContentStyles.feedMainImageContainer}>
          <Image source={source} style={feedContentStyles.feedMainImage} />
        </View>
      )}
      <Divider />
      <View style={contentStyles}>
        {deviceHelpers.isTablet && (
          <View style={feedContentStyles.feedMainImageContainerTablet}>
            <Image source={source} style={feedContentStyles.feedMainImage} />
          </View>
        )}
        <View style={contentFlexer}>
          <Text style={feedContentStyles.contentTitle}>
            {props.event.Title}
          </Text>
          <View style={[styles.detailsRow, { marginBottom: 8 }]}>
            <Icon
              name="date-range"
              size={16}
              color="rgba(0,0,0,0.5)"
              style={styles.icon}
            />
            <EventDate event={props.event} />
          </View>
          <View style={[styles.detailsRow, { marginBottom: 8 }]}>
            <Icon
              name="location-on"
              size={16}
              color="rgba(0,0,0,0.5)"
              style={styles.icon}
            />
            <Text style={styles.smallerText}>{eventLocation}</Text>
          </View>
          {displayTotal && (
            <View style={[styles.detailsRow, { marginBottom: 8 }]}>
              <Icon
                name="credit-card"
                size={16}
                color="rgba(0,0,0,0.54)"
                style={styles.icon}
              />
              <Text style={styles.smallerText}>{`$${props.grandTotal}`}</Text>
            </View>
          )}
          <Text style={feedContentStyles.parragraph}>
            {props.event.ShortDescription}
          </Text>
        </View>
      </View>
      {props.isRegistered && <Divider style={styles.dividerPusher} />}
      <View style={[feedContentStyles.footerActions, styles.footerActions]}>
        {
          props.isRegistered
          /* && (
          <TouchableOpacity
            style={styles.calendarBtn}
            onPress={props.handleAddToCalendar}
          >
            <Text style={styles.gothamBold14Black}>{"ADD TO CALENDAR"}</Text>
          </TouchableOpacity>
        ) */
        }
        <TextButton
          color={v2Colors.green}
          title={"VIEW DETAILS"}
          titleColor={v2Colors.white}
          onPress={props.mainActionButtonPress}
          titleStyle={v2ButtonStyles.titleStyle}
        />
      </View>
    </Card>
  );
};
```

`EventFeedCard` is the parent component to `Details` component:

```
export class Details extends Component {
  static propTypes = {
    auth: PropTypes.object,
    checkingUserMembership: PropTypes.bool,
    checkUserMembership: PropTypes.func,
    fetchSelectedEvent: PropTypes.func,
    isLapsedMember: PropTypes.bool,
    isMember: PropTypes.bool,
    loadingSelectedEvent: PropTypes.bool,
    navigation: PropTypes.object,
    primaryIndividual: PropTypes.object,
    selectedEvent: PropTypes.object,
    selectedPrice: PropTypes.object,
    setSelectedPrice: PropTypes.func,
    userKey: PropTypes.string,
    userOrganization: PropTypes.object
  };

  static navigationOptions = ({ navigation }) => ({
    title: navigation.state.params.title
  });

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    const prices = getDetailPrices(this.props);
    this.state = {
      userOpenedMemberLink: false,
      appState: AppState.currentState,
      ...prices
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.props.fetchSelectedEvent();
    this.props.checkUserMembership();
    AppState.addEventListener("change", this._handleAppStateChange);

    if (this.props.isMember && !this.props.isLapsedMember) {
      this._selectMemberPrice();
    }
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    AppState.removeEventListener("change", this._handleAppStateChange);
  }

  _selectMemberPrice = () => {
    const price = this.state.individualPrices.find(p => p.IsMemberPrice);
    if (price) {
      this.props.setSelectedPrice(price);
    }
  };

  _handleAppStateChange = async appState => {
    if (
      this.state.appState.match(/inactive|background/) &&
      appState === "active"
    ) {
      this.props.checkUserMembership();
    }
  };

  _validateCapacity = selectedEvent => {
    if (selectedEvent.NumberOfSeatsAvailable === 0) {
      Alert.alert(
        "Capacity Exceeded",
        capacityLimit,
        [
          {
            text: "OK",
            onPress: () => false,
            style: "cancel"
          }
        ],
        { cancelable: false }
      );

      return false;
    }

    return true;
  };

  _alertNoTableSeats = () => {
    Alert.alert(
      "Capacity Exceeded",
      capacityLimitTable,
      [
        {
          text: "OK",
          onPress: () => false,
          style: "cancel"
        }
      ],
      { cancelable: false }
    );
  };

  _navigate = () => {
    const {
      selectedEvent,
      isMember,
      selectedPrice,
      isLapsedMember
    } = this.props;
    const hasSeats = this._validateCapacity(selectedEvent);
    console.log("Validating Seating Capacity to be: ", hasSeats);

    if (hasSeats) {
      if (selectedEvent.IsFree) {
        //eslint-disable-next-line
        if (selectedEvent.IsMembersOnly && (!isMember || isLapsedMember)) {
          this._alertMembershipIssue();
        } else {
          this.props.navigation.navigate("EventRegistration");
        }
      } else if (selectedPrice) {
        //eslint-disable-next-line
        this.props.navigation.navigate("EventRegistration");
      } else {
        Alert.alert(
          "Event Pricing",
          "Please select a price before continuing.",
          [
            {
              text: "OK",
              onPress: () => false,
              style: "cancel"
            }
          ],
          { cancelable: false }
        );
      }
    }
  };

  _loginAsMember = (price = null) => {
    this.props.navigation.navigate("MembershipConfirmation", { price });
  };

  _canSelectPrice = price => {
    if (price.IsMemberPrice && this.props.isLapsedMember) {
      return false;
    }

    if (!this.props.isMember && price.IsMemberPrice) {
      return false;
    }

    return true;
  };

  _tableSeatsAvailable = price => {
    if (
      price.IsTable &&
      this.props.selectedEvent.NumberOfSeatsAvailable < price.NumberOfSeats
    ) {
      return false;
    }
    return true;
  };

  _selectPrice = async price => {
    const canSelect = this._canSelectPrice(price);
    if (canSelect) {
      const tableSeatsAvailable = this._tableSeatsAvailable(price);
      if (tableSeatsAvailable) {
        this.props.setSelectedPrice(price);
      } else {
        this._alertNoTableSeats();
      }
    } else {
      this._alertMembershipIssue(price);
    }
  };

  _alertMembershipIssue = (price = null) => {
    const { isLapsedMember, userKey } = this.props;
    const buttons = [
      {
        text: isLapsedMember ? "Renew Membership" : "Join NFIB",
        onPress: () => {
          let url = `${env.membershipJoinLink}=${userKey}`;
          if (isLapsedMember) {
            const { userOrganization, primaryIndividual } = this.props;
            const { PostalCode: zip } = userOrganization.Addresses[0];
            const lastName = primaryIndividual.PersonalDetails.LastName;
            const memberID = userOrganization.Id;
            //prettier-ignore
            url = `${env.membershipRenewLink}?lname=${lastName}&mid=${memberID}&zip=${zip}`;
          }
          Linking.openURL(url);
          this.setState({ userOpenedMemberLink: true });
        }
      },
      {
        text: "Cancel",
        onPress: () => false,
        style: "cancel"
      }
    ];

    if (!isLapsedMember) {
      buttons.unshift({
        text: "I am a Member",
        onPress: () => this._loginAsMember(price)
      });
    }

    Alert.alert(
      isLapsedMember ? "Renew Membership" : "Members Only",
      memberMsg,
      buttons,
      { cancelable: false }
    );
  };
  // clicking on VIEW DETAILS from EventFeedCard component fires off this if conditional
  render() {
    if (this.props.loadingSelectedEvent) {
      console.log(
        "Loading from Details component: ",
        this.props.loadingSelectedEvent
      );
      return <Loading />;
    }

    return (
      <EventDetails
        event={this.props.selectedEvent}
        handleRegistrationButtonPress={this._navigate}
        handleSelectPrice={this._selectPrice}
        tablePrices={this.state.tablePrices}
        individualPrices={this.state.individualPrices}
        selectedPrice={this.props.selectedPrice}
        checkingUserMembership={this.props.checkingUserMembership}
      />
    );
  }
}
```

Clicking on `REGISTER FOR EVENTS` from `EventDetails` component which is a child of `EventFeedCard and`Details`:

```
const EventDetails = props => {
  return (
    <SafeAreaView style={styles.container}>
      <ScrollView contentContainerStyle={styles.list}>
        <EventMainDetails event={props.event} displayRemainingSeats={true} />
        <View style={styles.cardsContainer}>
          {!deviceHelpers.isTablet && <PhoneEventDescription {...props} />}
          {deviceHelpers.isTablet && <TabletEventDescription {...props} />}
          {props.event.IsRestricted && (
            <Text style={styles.restrictedText}>{restrictedText}</Text>
          )}
        </View>
      </ScrollView>
      {!props.event.IsRestricted && (
        <TouchableOpacity
          style={[styles.footer, styles.rowFooter]}
          onPress={props.handleRegistrationButtonPress}
        >
          {props.checkingUserMembership ? (
            {
              /* <ActivityIndicator /> */
            }
          ) : (
            <Text style={styles.footerBtnText}>
              {"HOWDY! REGISTER FOR EVENT"}
            </Text>
          )}
        </TouchableOpacity>
      )}
    </SafeAreaView>
  );
};
```

triggers the redirect to `EventRegistrationForm`:

```
const EventRegistrationForm = ({
  badgeNameError,
  currentUser,
  displayGuestErrors,
  event,
  eventBadgeName,
  grandTotal,
  guestUsers,
  handleAddGuestButtonPress,
  handleBadgeNameInputChange,
  handleGuestFirstNameChange,
  handleGuestLastNameChange,
  handlePaymentsButtonPress,
  handleRemoveGuestButtonPress,
  selectedPrice,
  userOrganization,
}) => {
  const displayPersonal = event.IsFree || !selectedPrice.IsTable;
  const roomForGuests =
    (event.NumberOfSeatsAvailable || 0) > guestUsers.length + 1;
  const displayAddButton =
    (event.IsFree || roomForGuests) && !(selectedPrice || {}).IsTable;

  return (
    <SafeAreaView style={styles.container}>
      <KeyboardAwareScrollView
        contentContainerStyle={{paddingBottom: 121}}
        showsVerticalScrollIndicator={false}
        keyboardShouldPersistTaps={'handled'}
        enableOnAndroid={true}
        extraHeight={90}
      >
        <EventMainDetails
          event={event}
          currentUser={currentUser}
          displayRemainingSeats={true}
        />
        <View style={styles.cardsContainer}>
          {selectedPrice &&
            selectedPrice.IsTable && (
              <Card style={styles.tablePriceCard} tappable={false}>
                <Text style={styles.contentTitle}>
                  {selectedPrice.TableName}
                </Text>
                <Text style={styles.contentTitle}>
                  {`$${selectedPrice.Price}`}
                </Text>
              </Card>
            )}
          {displayPersonal && (
            <EventRegistrationFormPersonalDetails
              handleBadgeNameInputChange={handleBadgeNameInputChange}
              eventBadgeName={eventBadgeName}
              currentUser={currentUser}
              eventPrice={selectedPrice && selectedPrice.Price}
              userOrganization={
                userOrganization && userOrganization.OrganizationDetails.Name
              }
              badgeNameError={badgeNameError}
            />
          )}
          <EventRegistrationGuestForm
            handleGuestLastNameChange={handleGuestLastNameChange}
            handleGuestFirstNameChange={handleGuestFirstNameChange}
            guestUsers={guestUsers}
            handleRemoveGuestButtonPress={handleRemoveGuestButtonPress}
            isTableGuest={selectedPrice && selectedPrice.IsTable}
            displayGuestErrors={displayGuestErrors}
          />
          {!displayAddButton &&
            !selectedPrice.IsTable && (
              <Text>
                {
                  'You cannot add more guests to this event. If you have questions, please contact NFIB by calling the number provided in the event details or 1-800-NFIB-NOW.'
                }
              </Text>
            )}
          {displayAddButton && (
            <View style={guestbtnStyle}>
              <TextButton
                title={'ADD A GUEST'}
                color={v2Colors.green}
                titleColor={v2Colors.white}
                onPress={handleAddGuestButtonPress}
                titleStyle={v2ButtonStyles.titleStyle}
              />
            </View>
          )}
        </View>
      </KeyboardAwareScrollView>
      <View style={styles.footer}>
        {!event.IsFree && (
          <View style={styles.eventTotal}>
            <Text style={styles.totalText}>{'Total'}</Text>
            <Text style={[styles.totalText, {fontWeight: 'bold'}]}>
              {`$${grandTotal}`}
            </Text>
          </View>
        )}
        <TouchableOpacity
          style={styles.rowFooter}
          onPress={handlePaymentsButtonPress}
        >
          {event.IsFree && (
            <Text style={styles.footerBtnText}>{'REGISTER FOR EVENT'}</Text>
          )}
          {!event.IsFree && (
            <Text style={styles.footerBtnText}>{'CONTINUE TO PAYMENT'}</Text>
          )}
        </TouchableOpacity>
      </View>
    </SafeAreaView>
  );
};
```

When the user clicks on `REGISTER FOR EVENT` there once, it fires the `saveRegistration` async function from `events/helpers/action-helpers`:

```
export async function saveRegistration(
      { selectedEvent, registrationsData, paymentsData },
      user
    ) {
      try {
        const numberOfSeats = getNumberOfSeats(registrationsData);
        console.log("How many seats: ", numberOfSeats);

    const isValid = await isCapacityValid(selectedEvent, numberOfSeats);
    console.log("Are there still some seats left?", isValid);
    // when REGISTER FOR EVENT is clicked, it does not fire the message below even though !isValid
    if (!isValid) {
      console.log("Clicked the button a second time: ", !isValid);
      return Promise.reject({
        Message:
          "Thank you for your interest in this NFIB event. Currently, no seats are available. If you have questions, please contact NFIB by calling the number provided in the event description or 1-800-NFIB-NOW."
      });
    }
```

The first time this is clicked, it should give the user the alert message you see above in `Promise.reject`, but that does not happen until the user clicks the `REGISTER FOR EVENT` a second time and the message alert appears for a second and then the `<Loading />` component with its animated gif runs indefinitely and freezes the app up. I have not been able to determine which `<Loading />` component peppered throughout this app it is running as there are many that come inside of `if` conditionals. I am still going through them, but does anyone have any idea what could be going on?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because Promise is synchronous, you may be waiting for the next function. I think it's good to solve this problem through basic usage

```js
return await Promise.reject({
        Message:
          "Thank you for your interest in this NFIB event. Currently, no seats are available. If you have questions, please contact NFIB by calling the number provided in the event description or 1-800-NFIB-NOW."
      }).then(function(reason) {
  // Not called.
}, function(reason) {
  console.log(reason); // [object object]
});
```

If you want to use both resolve and reject, you can:

```js
return await new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
      if (isValid) {
        resolve("resolve");
      } else {
         reject({
           Message:
             "Thank you for your interest in this NFIB event. Currently, no seats are available. If you have questions, please contact NFIB by calling the number provided in the event description or 1-800-NFIB-NOW."
         });
      }
    });
```

Comment: after implementing your solution and the user clicking REGISTER FOR EVENT, it indeed does execute that message, in the console. How would you write this so that the message prints as an alert to the user? I mean I know I can do an `alert()` but would I just pass `Message` or `e.message`? Not sure.

Comment: now that my Promise memory banks are being jogged, shouldn't that say `return await Promise.resolve()`? We can't run a `.then()` on a `rejected` promise, only on a `resolved` one, is that not correct?

Comment: @Daniel If you show the contents of the error in a warning statement, you will be able to solve the problem quickly because you can directly help users solve the error, but from the user's point of view, you won't think it's a good app to use or look at.

Comment: It would be better to find a way to distinguish error through a simple message. In the case of a common error, common error message contents and changing mains depending on screen is a good way to do so.

Comment: When not rejected, the value in the resolve is returned.

Comment: ex) `var promise1 = Promise.resolve("resolve"); promise1.then(function(value) {
  console.log(value);
  // expected output: "resolve"
});`

Comment: this solution works for iOS, but not for Android, instead of resolve I get reject.

Comment: @Daniel I edited my answer. Would you like to give it a try?